# How to fix Talkback announcing checked state change multiple times when changing radio button selection on Google Chrome for Android

Tags: browser, radio-button, accessibility, talkback

I'm working on a AA accessible web application where I have a simple form with radio button group. When I have already selected a radio button and change the selection, Android Talkback announces state changes twice.
It would say, "unchecked checked" or "checked unchecked".

My markup is strictly following the accessibility guidelines as described here https://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls#radio. I'm not even sure if this is a bug or feature.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bhargavshah/pen/PXVBML

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose a shipping method:</legend>
    <input id="overnight" type="radio" name="shipping" value="overnight">
    <label for="overnight">Overnight</label><br>
    <input id="twoday" type="radio" name="shipping" value="twoday">
    <label for="twoday">Two day</label><br>
    <input id="ground" type="radio" name="shipping" value="ground">
    <label for="ground">Ground</label>
</fieldset>
```

**Expected Result**: Talkback should just announce "Checked" on a radio button when selection changes.

**Actual Result**: Talkback announces "Unchecked checked" on a radio button when selection changes.

Comment: At first glance, your HTML code seem to be correct. Could you post an example online ? It would be easier to test and find out what might confuse talkback.
Perhaps it has to do with some JavaScript.


Additional note, if you can: I find the title a little confusing. When clicking on the question, I thought that you wanted to disable state changes announcements.

Comment: @QuentinC Updated the question title, and added a Codepen. Appreciate you looking at this :)

Comment: I won't be able to help you further, I don't have any android phone currently and it seems to work correctly everywhere else (iOS, Jaws/NVDA+Firefox). But now the title is much more adequate, thank you.

Comment: @QuentinC Yes, it is specific to Android. Thank you.

Comment: Same happens to me using Polymer, it says touble tap to toggle then on-off whenever I touch out of the screen... it doesnt make sense. did u find any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just came across this post as I was looking for an answer to a different question related to checkboxes, but just in case you never got your answer, this is not a defect. This is expected screen reader behavior to tell you the current state of the item followed by the new state.

Comment: Could you attach a link that documents this behavior?